# Unable to hit the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, url

I have a design for product display in Ecommerce web application in which when I place the cursor it shows an Eye button when I click on
 it, It should display more information about the product.

Html Code of the product is below

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="product-carousel">
                    @{foreach(var item in Model.ProductList)
                      {
                    <div class="single-product-box">
                        <div class="product-thumb">
                            <img src="~/Content/ProductImages/@item.ProductImages" alt="product image">
                            <div class="product-hover">
                                <div class="product-table">
                                    <div class="product-table-cell">
                                        <a href="#"><i class="icofont icofont-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                        <a href="/Muminoon/Index/@item.ProductId" data-target="#product_model" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icofont icofont-eye"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#"><i class="icofont icofont-ui-love"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-details text-center">
                            <h4>@item.ProductName</h4>
                            <span class="size">Price</span>
                            <span class="price">@item.Price</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        }
                      }



                </div>
            </div>
```

Html Code when eye button is clicked it should be redirected to below

```
<div class="modal fade" id="product_model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="product-model-body">
                    @{
                        if (Model.ProductListWithId !=null)
                        {


                    <div class="row">
                        @{foreach(var item in Model.ProductListWithId)
                        {
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="product-thumb">
                                <img src="~/Content/ProductImages/@item.ProductImages" alt="product thumb">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="modal-product-details">
                                <div class="model-product-header">
                                    <h6>@item.ProductName</h6>
                                    <div class="product-review">
                                        <div class="product-rating">
                                            <i class="icofont icofont-star"></i>
                                            <i class="icofont icofont-star"></i>
                                            <i class="icofont icofont-star"></i>
                                            <i class="icofont icofont-star"></i>
                                            <i class="icofont icofont-star"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="sep">|</span>
                                        <p class="review-count">5 Reviews</p>
                                        <span class="sep">|</span>
                                        <p class="rating-text">Add Your Rating</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="price">@item.OfferPrice <del>@item.Price</del></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="model-product-body">
                                    @*<p class="sku">SKU: Men-8898</p>
                                    <p class="p-color">Color: <span></span><span></span><span></span></p>*@
                                    <div class="p-size">
                                        <label for="size">Size</label>
                                        <select name="size" id="size">
                                            <option value="0">S</option>
                                            <option value="1">M</option>
                                            <option value="2">L</option>
                                            <option value="3">XL</option>
                                            <option value="4">XXL</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="quantity">
                                        <div class="minus"><i class="icofont icofont-minus" id="minus"></i></div>
                                        <div id="quant" class="quant">1</div>
                                        <div class="plus"><i class="icofont icofont-plus" id="plus"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="model-product-footer">
                                    <div class="buy-button">
                                        <a href="#" class="boxed-btn"><i class="icofont icofont-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                        <a href="#" class="favorite-btn"><i class="icofont icofont-ui-love"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        }
                        }
                    </div>
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

But when I'm clicking the Eye button it's not hitting when I place a breakpoint, what should I do?

Comment: Make sure that URL generated in anchor tag is perfect and appropriate controller and action with respective params exist.

Comment: @AltafKhokhar URL generated in anchor tag is perfect but still it's not functioning